# How to fix org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement expected "identifier"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I am using H2 in-memory database for my springboot application. Where I have enabled `hibernate.ddl-auto`. I am getting below exception while hibernate is creating a schema

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException:
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_OFFSET_INFO (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP, OFFSET[*] BIGINT, TOPIC_NAME VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table PRODUCT_OFFSET_INFO (ID bigint not null, MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP timestamp, OFFSET bigint, TOPIC_NAME varchar(255), primary key (ID)) [42001-200]
'''
```

Below is the Entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_OFFSET_INFO")
public class ProductOffsetInfo implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -2147468513335906679L;
    
   @Id
   @Column(name="ID")
   private Long ProductId;
    
   @Column(name="TOPIC_NAME")
   private String topic_name;
    
   @Column(name="OFFSET")
   private Long offset;
    
   @Column(name = "MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP")
   private Date modified;
    
   public Long getProductId() {
       return ProductId;
   }
   public void setProductId(Long ProductId) {
       this.ProductId = ProductId;
   }
    
   public String getTopic_name() {
       return topic_name;
   }
   public void setTopic_name(String topic_name) {
       this.topic_name = topic_name;
   }
    
   public Long getOffset() {
       return offset;
   }
   public void setOffset(Long offset) {
       this.offset = offset;
   }
    
   public Date getModified() {
       return modified;
   }
    
   public void setModified(Date modified) {
       this.modified = modified;
   }
}
```

Below is the database config file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "productEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "productTransactionManager",
    basePackages = {"com.product.repository.product"}
)
@ComponentScan({"com.product.repository.product.impl"})
@EntityScan({"com.product.commons.entities.product.models","com.product.models.product"})
public class ProductDbConfig {

        @Autowired
        private JpaProperties jpaProperties;
        @Primary
        @Bean("productHikariConfig")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
        public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
            return new HikariConfig();
        }
    
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "productDataSource")
        @DependsOn("productHikariConfig")
        public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("productHikariConfig") HikariConfig hikariConfig) {
            return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        }
    
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "productEntityManagerFactory")
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "product")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("productDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(datasource).properties(jpaProperties.getProperties())
                    .packages("com.product.commons.entities.product.models","com.product.models.product")
                    .persistenceUnit("product")
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "productTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
                @Qualifier("productEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }
    }
```

Below is the `application.yml` content for DB

```
    spring:
      profiles: mock
      jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        generate-ddl: true
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: create
      datasource:
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:PRODUCT
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
        maximumPoolSize: 10
        minimumIdle: 5
        idleTimeout: 60000
        maxLifetime: 120000
        leakDetectionThreshold: 180000
        poolName: "product"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to correct this:

```java
@Column(name="OFFSET")
private Long offset;
```

to

```java
@Column(name="`OFFSET`")
private Long offset;
```

As `OFFSET` is [reserved keyword](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords) you should force Hibernate to quote an identifier in the generated SQL by enclosing the column name in backticks in the mapping document. See [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers) of hibernate documentation.

Comment: After looking for a whole day why my table is not created with Hibernate in the H2 database I found this answer. You are awesome! @sternk    
  Adding those ` at my column name `key` finally did the trick.  
The issue appeared with upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5 and H2 2.1.210 and worked fine previously.

Comment: I had the same problem because of another reserved keyword, a table called `user`.

Comment: this is applicable to table names as well , "User" is a reserved keywork in H2 DB , i resolved the same exception during spring boot project startup it in the same way as described in the answer.

Comment: I also had the same issue dealing with a vehicle database, it did not like the `year` attribute ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same but none of the solutions worked, but if i did the below it worked fine.

Updated the dialect from " `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`"

to "`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`"

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the accepted answer, I want to highlight an alternate way.

We can add "NON_KEYWORDS=OFFSET" in the spring.datasource.url property in properties file.

This works for the reserved keywords used as column name but also in table name. Like, User table name.