# Oracle and H2 Table with Keyword in Column

Tags: java, spring, oracle, h2, junit4

I have a Oracle table, say, `mytbl`, which has a column, `OFFSET`. I am trying to create unit tests using `H2` and because `OFFSET` is a keyword for `H2`, I am having to re-write the queries using a double quoted, `"OFFSET"`, instead of simply referring to the column as `offset`. I am using SpringFramework's `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` to spinup the H2. When instantiating the database for unit tests, I use the specification, `NON_KEYWORDS=OFFSET`, in the url. This specification is honored during instantiation, that is, I can refer to the column simply as `offset`. But the `NON_KEYWORDS` spec is ignored when the actual queries are invoked.

FWIW:

- versions: H2:2.1.x, Oracle:19.4, Java:11, jUnit:4, Spring:5.3.x.
- I am **not** using JPA or Hibernate.
- SO references: [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695039/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlsyntaxerrorexception-after-h2-version-upgrade), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333101/how-to-fix-org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlsyntaxerrorexception-syntax-error-in-sql-statemen)

Here is the test class (the actual tests are irrelevant):

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;

public class MyClassDaoTest {
  private EmbeddedDatabase ds;
  private MyClassDao myClassDao;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    this.ds = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                  .setType( EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2 )
                  .setName( "dummy;MODE=Oracle;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=true;NON_KEYWORDS=OFFSET" )
                  .addScript( "/initialize-mytbl.sql" )
                  .build();
    this.myClassDao = new MyClassDao( new JdbcTemplate( this.ds ) );
  }

  @After
  public void shutdown() {
    this.ds.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Here is the loading script (note: I do not have to use `"OFFSET"` here), *initialize-mytbl.sql*:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTBL ( offset INTEGER NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO MYTBL ( offset ) VALUES (1);
```

And here is the actual query:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;

public class MyClassDao {
  private final JdbcOperation j;
  public MyClassDao( JdbcOperations j ) { this.j = j; }
  public int fetchOffset() {
    // this fails in H2 but works in Oracle:
    //return j.queryForObject( "select offset from mytbl", Integer.class );
    // this works in both H2 and Oracle:
    return j.queryForObject( "select \"OFFSET\" from mytbl", Integer.class );
  }
}
```

So, my question is: why is the `NON_KEYWORDS` spec in the url being ignored in the actual queries? Obviously, I do not prefer to re-write all the queries replacing `offset` with `"OFFSET"`. And, more obviously, I can not alter the Oracle table, `mytbl`.

The actual exception thrown is:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT offset[*] from mytbl" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Few database systems such as PostgreSQL and H2 allow empty lists of select expressions, so it is possible to execute `SELECT OFFSET 0 ROWS` etc. in them. `NON_KEYWORDS` setting in H2 only works well when specified keywords don't conflict with any other grammar constructions, parser isn't that smart to see `FROM` after `OFFSET` when it determines whether `OFFSET` a keyword or an identifier.

Modern versions of Oracle also support standard `OFFSET` / `FETCH` clauses, but empty lists of select expressions are invalid, Oracle doesn't expect `OFFSET` / `FETCH` clauses here, it expects only an expression and its parser also uses additional quirks to distinguish the `OFFSET` clause from `OFFSET` identifier in other contexts, such as aliases (`SELECT * FROM TEST OFFSET`).

If you really need to use both database systems, `OFFSET` needs to be quoted in queries, currently there are no other solutions.